# Draw a scale-free network in a lattice

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want to generate graph form an adjacency list but I am not happy with how the nodes are positioned. I want them to be positioned according to a pre-defined scheme which resembles a regular grid with arbitrary coordinates x and y, while still maintaining the scale-free features.   Let me give an example: A barabasi-albert network with node 1 located at x_1 = 0.6 and y_1 = 0.5, node 2 located at x_2 = -0.5 and y_2 = 1 ... and so on. I have a list of coordinates of each node.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `pos` parameter of draw_networkx_XXX functions [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#id2).

It can be used like this:

```
 import networkx as nx
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from random import randint,seed; 

 seed(1)
 nodes = list(range(5))
 edges = [ (nodes[i-1],nodes[i]) for i in range(1,len(nodes)) ]
 # here we can set the coordinates to our liking
 positions = { node:(randint(0,9),randint(0,9)) for node in nodes }
 G=nx.Graph()
 G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
 G.add_edges_from(edges)
 nx.draw_networkx(G,pos=positions, with_labels=False, node_size=100)
 plt.show()
```

[image: output]

**[Edit]**

Here's how we can build the graph from the adjancency list and assign real values to node positions.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint,seed 
from pprint import pprint

seed(0)
edges = [ (randint(0,5),randint(0,5)) for i in range(5) ]
G=nx.Graph()
# nodes added automatically with add_edges_from
G.add_edges_from(edges)
# here we can set positions to our liking
positions = { node: (round((5-randint(0,9))/7.0,2)
                    , round((5-randint(0,9))/7.0,2)) for node in G.nodes }
pprint({ "edges:": edges, "nodes:":list(G.nodes), "positions:":positions }, width=100)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = positions, with_labels=False, node_size=100)
plt.show()
```

[image: output for real values]

Using positions from a csv file is straightforward.
The `pos` parameter is really supposed to be a dict with node names as keys (I edited the first snippet to reflect that).
So, if we have a csv file with node names and positions, we just build a dict from it and supply the dict for `pos`.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I still have a doubt.

If insteaf of edges = [ (nodes[i-1],nodes[i]) for i in range(1,len(nodes)) ] I have a file .csv with adjacency list and instead of 
 positions = [ (randint(0,9),randint(0,9)) for node in nodes ]
I have a csv file with the positions (real number, including negative numbers).

I can not do the drawing.

Comment: Are the positions in the csv file given for nodes or edges?